# How to find biggest files in cluster

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql, psqlodbc

Postgres 13 cluster in Debian Linux server contains 30 databases. Databases contain number of schemas.
How to find biggest files which occupy most space in disk ?
I tried

```
select
    relname::char(25),
    pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(c.oid))::char(10) as totalsize,
    n.nspname::char(12),
    case
        when c.relkind='i' then 'index'
        when c.relkind='t' then 'toast'
        when c.relkind='r' then 'table'
        when c.relkind='v' then 'view'
        when c.relkind='c' then 'composite type'
        when c.relkind='S' then 'sequence'
        else c.relkind::text
      end ::char(14) as "type"
from
    pg_class c
    left join pg_namespace n on n.oid = c.relnamespace
    left join pg_tablespace t on t.oid = c.reltablespace
where
    (pg_total_relation_size(c.oid)>>21)>0 order by
    pg_total_relation_size(c.oid) desc
```

But it returns sizes for current database only. How to run in over whole cluster ? Can some plpgsql script used for this.
Output should include database name column.

Client application uses psqlODBC to get data so psql or shell scripts should preferably avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that, as you can only query the database to which you are connected. You need to connect to each database in turn.

Comment: How to create PL/pgSQL script which runs query in every database and consolidates results to single table. Maybe there is some generic script for this which can used to run same quuery is all databases.

Comment: As I said, you cannot do that, since a PL/pgSQL function always runs in a single database session. Use a shell script or something like that.

Comment: Can PL/pgSQL call  postgres_fdw to retrieve data from other databases in cluster.

Comment: Sure,  why not?.

Comment: Where to find PL/pgSQL sample code which enumerates all user databases in cluster and runs some command on them ?

Comment: Can PL/pgSQL script use DbLink to connect to cluster, get list of databases and run query in each database ? It can use different connection string for every database